# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 using API 28 only

Tags: java, android, json, http, okhttp

I'm developing an android app that sends requests and gets responses from my server using ASYNC tasks and OkHttp. When parsing the response:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BaseUrl+"/api/user")
                .get()
                .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer "+ jwt)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String stream = response.body().string();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stream.toString());
        String instance = jsonObject.getString("name");
        return instance;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "no";
}
```

I get an `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0`
 exception.

However, the request is tested via postman and the response is correct and not null.
Moreover, when testing the app using API 26 or 27, everything works just fine, this happens only when using API 28.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This error comes when json is malformed. So please post your response body for better analysis.

Comment: @UllasHunka Well, actually the json is fine. I just can't post it here since its too long. But i made sure it is a clean json using postman. Moreover, if the json was malformed it wouldn't have worked on any API